# Delays with angular universal and ngIf checks - Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm just starting to integrate angular universal in the already existing application and I'm noticing that for a second the page renders with the wrong layout and when the page fully loads everything looks fine.

**This is an example:**

I'm getting the login status on page load like this:

```
this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(res => {
  this.isLoggedIn = res;
});
```

And setting a different layout depending on the result if true or false:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="user-logged">
    // user logged in
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="user-logged">
    // user not logged in
</div>
```

But when the service returns true (which means the user is logged in), for a second, I can see the not logged in status then the page loads and everything looks fine.
This also happens with all BreakpointObserver checks.

**UPDATE 1:**
This is what I've tried:
I've created an AppConfigService:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService {

  private isLoggedStatus: boolean;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.isLoggedStatus;
  }

  load() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.authService.isLoggedIn.subscribe(loggedInStatus => {
        this.isLoggedStatus = loggedInStatus;
        resolve(true);
      });
    });
  }

}
```

In my AuthService:

```
private isLoginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.isAuthenticated);

get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoginSubject.asObservable();
}

get isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    const token = this.getToken();
    if (token) {
      if (jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

In my app.module.ts

```
export function appConfigFactory(provider: AppConfigService) {
  return () => provider.load();
}

providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: appConfigFactory,
        deps: [AppConfigService],
        multi: true
    }
]
```

I think the problem is about the use of the localstorage on server side, but if that's the problem how do I check if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because, when your app first evaluates the `isLoggedIn`, it is false (or undefined, it depends on how you defined it).

Then, when the subscribe event returns the data, `isLoggedIn` value changes so your html changes too because of your `*ngIf` condition.

If you want to load the `isLoggedIn` data before the app renders, you can use `APP_INITIALIZER`.

This post explains how to use it: https://www.cidean.com/blog/2019/initialize-data-before-angular-app-starts/

This one's older but good too: https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/10/17/angular-preload/

## EDIT

In your `AppConfigService`, `isLoggedStatus` should be an Observable, or it will be undefined (and evaluate to false) until the Promise resolves.

You should wait un til the promise ends to render your component.

Example steps:

- Display login page.
- When user hits **login**, call your server and wait for the response.
- IF success:

  - `isLoggedStatus` = **true**
  - save session (in `LocalStorage` if you want)
  - display your component (and `isLoggedIn` will be true)
- IF failure:

  - `isLoggedStatus` = **false**
  - display your component (and `isLoggedIn` will be false)
  - user should have the opportunity to retry login

Comment: I've just tried this and it still doesn't work. With a console.log() of the isLoggedIn response from the AppConfigService I'm getting two different result. In the browser console I'm getting a true value and in the ssr server console I'm getting a false value. I can update my answer with what I've done.

Comment: Actually, I think I found the problem. On the server side, localstorage.getItem('toke') returns null, but in the browser it returns the actual token value

Comment: Yes, update the question please. `LocalStorage` should not be available in the server, only in the browser.

Comment: Yes! I just did. Not sure how to solve the problem if the LocalStorage is not avavilable in the server.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you use `localStorage`. The server side version of you app cannot access local storage (like it cannot access the `window`, `navigator` on any browser object), so it considers the user as not connected.

When working with angular universal and authentication, you can use cookies, that the server can access.

There are a few libraries available, but from what I've looked they are not fully ready to use with angular 9:

- [ngx-cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie)

  Work around for angular 9 in this [github issue](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie/issues/106).
- [ngx-cookie-service](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service)

  Does not work with for angular universal [github issue](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service/issues/1)